# Problema al crear clave foránea de dos campos

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema con la clave foránea de la tabla `empleados`. He probado a juntar 2 claves foráneas en una (como se ve) y a ponerlas individualmente, pero solo obtenemos el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

Este es el SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE departamentos (
      numero integer(1),
      centro integer(3),
      director integer(1),
      tipo_dir char(1),
      presupuesto integer(10),
      depto_jefe integer(2),
      nombre char(10),
      CHECK (tipo_dir IN('F','P')),
      CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY(centro,director,numero)      
);

CREATE TABLE empleados (
      cod integer(1),
      departamento integer(1),
      telefono integer(9),
      fecha_nacimiento date,
      fecha_ingreso date,
      salario integer(5),
      comision integer(2),
      num_hijos integer(2),
      nombre char(10),
      CONSTRAINT pk2 PRIMARY KEY(departamento,cod),
      CONSTRAINT fk4 FOREIGN KEY(departamento,cod) REFERENCES departamentos(numero,director)      
);

CREATE TABLE centros (
      numero integer(3),
      nombre char(10),
      direccion char(20),
      CONSTRAINT pk3 PRIMARY KEY(numero),
      CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY(numero) REFERENCES empleados(departamento),
      CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY(numero) REFERENCES departamentos(centro)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema que sufres es debido a que el motor InnoDB de MySQL requiere que los primeros campos concuerden en orden con una clave de la tabla referenciada.

Te está fallando esta línea:

```
FOREIGN KEY(departamento,cod)
  REFERENCES departamentos(numero,director)
```

Debido a que el único índice de tu tabla `departamentos` es:

```
PRIMARY KEY(centro,director,numero)
```

Así que para solucionar tu problema solo necesitas hacer índice (`KEY`) o clave única (`UNIQUE`) la tupla `numero`/`director`:

```
ALTER TABLE departamentos
  ADD UNIQUE(numero,director);
```

O creando la tabla de nuevo:

```
CREATE TABLE departamentos (
      numero integer(1),
      centro integer(3),
      director integer(1),
      tipo_dir char(1),
      presupuesto integer(10),
      depto_jefe integer(2),
      nombre char(10),
      CHECK (tipo_dir IN('F','P')),
      CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY(centro,director,numero),
      UNIQUE(numero,director)
);
```

Puedes comprobar el funcionamiento en [esta prueba en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbmAysuhVi3buMWSdRbhfp/0).

La otra referencia funciona correctamente:

```
FOREIGN KEY(numero)
  REFERENCES empleados(departamento),
```

Debido a que `departamento` SÍ coincide en el orden con los índices de la tabla `empleados`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(departamento,cod),
```

No necesitas que coincidan TODOS los campos, sólo los primeros.

La limitación se explica en [la documentación de tablas externas/foráneas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order.

En castellano:

> InnoDB permite que una clave externa haga referencia a cualquier campo que sea índice o grupo de campos. Sin embargo en la tabla referenciada debe haber un índice donde el primero sea el mismo y el resto de campos referenciados estén en el mismo orden.